# I got MISSING_PERMISSION issue Here maps Android

Tags: android, permissions, here-api

I'm trying an application just show Here map on screen. I've followed all of steps in document of Here + provided app_id, app_code, license key + provided 6 permissions in AndroidManifest.xml.

But It got the following issue:

> "ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment: MISSING_PERMISSION"

I'm using gradle 2.8, targetSdkVersion 23, compileSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 6 / API 23 has a new permission system, that means you have to request critical permissions from the user. 
See Android docs: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Just adding the critical permissions to the manifest is not enough anymore.

If you don't want to do this, you can still set traget API level to 22 and work in legacy mode, but to be more future proof, you should implement the new Android6 way of requesting permissions.

The critical permissions in the HERE SDK that you have to request are: 
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've resolved my issue. I changed target API level down to 22. I discovered my issue: I provided 6 permissions in AndroidManifest.xml, but I put them on wrong position in Manifest. I should put them out of application tag, not in application tag

Comment: Why do you need ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to show the map? Isn't this permission only for requesting user's location?

Comment: The location permission is indeed only necessary when using the PositionManager, good catch. but the access to external storage is needed for the map data. Therefor you anyway have to handle the new permissions on android6 correctly

Comment: @Marco I understand that, but I was talking about location one :). ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION must NOT be critical permission in order for map to work. If I target 23 API and user uses android M devices, HERE map becomes useless(If user disallowed location, which is normal)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using android runtime permission on for location access as from marshmallow onward all the OS need permission to run